# CSS element reveal from left to right

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having two menu bars on my site. The first one (black) is fixed at the top of the page. The second one (orange) will get sticky, once the black bar hits it. In the same moment there's a small logo image appearing which was hidden by using a class named "inactve" with "display: none" and gets displayed by removing the class "inactive and adding the class "active" with "display: inline-block".

Animated gif here:
https://abload.de/img/animation1lujbu.gif

Live version here:
http://mydivision.net/

But the change from "display: none" to "display: inline-block" is pretty abrupt. Please can anyone hlep making this a nice transition with the logo being revealed from left to right, so that the social icons get pushed gently to the right?

**Here's my code:**

*HTML*

```
<div class="topbar-container">
    <div id="slc" class="notonmobile scroll-logo inactive">
        <a href="http://mydivision.net/" title="MYDIVISION.NET | Home">
            <img src="http://mydivision.net/wp-content/themes/v1/img/scroll-logo-small.png" alt="Logo" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="social_container">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
#topbar {display: inline-block; width: 100%; padding: 0; height: 40px; background: #000; position: fixed; top: 0; z-index: 9999;}
.topbar-container {margin: 6px 20px; line-height: 24px;}
.scroll-logo.inactive {display: none;}
.scroll-logo.active {display: inline-block; float: left; margin-right: 20px;}
.scroll-logo img {height: 24px; padding: 3px 0;}
#social_container {float: left; width: 192px;}
```

*jQuery*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.sticky-element-active').offset().top - 40) {
            $("#slc").addClass("active");
            $("#slc").removeClass("inactive");
        } else {
            $("#slc").removeClass("active");
            $("#slc").addClass("inactive");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove *active* and *inactive* from CSS and use the code below. Jquery **show()** and **hide()** cause expansion and contraction of elements when duration set for them.

But maintain *inactive* as class name in your html to make sure that expansion happens just one time every time the scroll condition happens:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.sticky-element-active').offset().top - 40 && $("#slc").hasClass("inactive")) {
            $("#slc").show(1000);
            $("#slc").removeClass("inactive");
        } else {
            $("#slc").hide(1000);
            $("#slc").addClass("inactive");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The result is an endless loop of the animation pushing everything else down instead of only the social icons to the right.

Comment: Please dont remove float:left from logo.

Comment: Thanks, but I still have an infinite loop of the animation. Had to remove " && $("#slc").hasClass("inactive")" from the script and the loop was gone.

Comment: One more thing: How can I edit the script to only do this when the window width is 768px or bigger? It should also detect resizing of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I had some luck modifying your live CSS. You could play with the transition times and tweak it further, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

```
.scroll-logo.inactive {
  transition: 0.8s;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.scroll-logo.active {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Thank you Andy, I'll play a bit with this.

Comment: Any idea how to make it smoother for the logo to disappear agin? The social icons just pop back to the initial position. So from opacity 0 to 1 it's smooth, but not from 1 to 0.

Comment: The way I would do this from scratch would be to create custom CSS animations, one for each element, and trigger them using using a single parent class. You would toggle a single class on, say, `body`, and the animations would respond to the existence of that class. It's called a delegate pattern. The jQuery solution is easy, but you have no control of the animation style.